# How to add a drop shadow to a view while masksToBounds is true?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

So normally when you have a view and you want to add a drop shadow I do something like this:

```
UIBezierPath *shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:diptic.bounds];
diptic.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
diptic.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
diptic.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
diptic.layer.shadowRadius = 10;
diptic.layer.shadowOpacity = .5f;
diptic.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath;
```

Where diptic is my UIScrollView.

The problem is that because diptic is a scroll view, that I have content in the scroll view that I don't want to be on the screen until they scroll to it, so I want to have masksToBounds set to YES but if I do that then I can't see my shadow..

[image: iphone screenshot]

you can see the description of the dartboard ("A basically new dartboard...") I want to be hidden until the user scrolls to it. Also, the rounded corners of the diptic isn't clipping the square corners on the top of the image.

Is there any way to be selective of what is masked and what isn't?

Answer (score 0):

Put `diptic` into another view with the same bounds, that way you can mask `diptic` to bounds but apply the shadow to the containing view that wouldn't have its content masked to its bounds.

Comment: That's what I think I have to do. I created another view that sits just behind the 'diptic'. And manipulate it the same way whenever I have to manipulate 'diptic'. It isn't the most ideal but it works.